# LDAP client can connect to LDAP host but can't see LDAP users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap, openldap, ubuntu-14.04

I'm configuring LDAP on a cluster of Ubuntu 14.04 machines.

I successfully set up the LDAP host using [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-openldap-and-phpldapadmin-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server).  Now I'm trying to get an LDAP client to work using [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-client-computers-using-ldap-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps).

ldapsearch works from the client (i.e. I can do `ldapsearch -x -LLL -h REDACTED -D REDACTED -w REDACTED -b REDACTED` from the client machine and get exactly the results I would expect).

However, the client machine doesn't see the LDAP users at all (i.e. `getent passwd` doesn't show any LDAP users, `sudo su - LDAP_USERNAME` on the client machine returns `No passwd entry for user` error, `ssh LDAP_USERNAME@LDAP_CLIENT` gets a `Permission denied` error).

Relevant files:

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:         ldap compat
group:          ldap compat
shadow:         ldap compat

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup: nis
```

/etc/pam.d/common-session

```
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so

session requisite                       pam_deny.so

session required                        pam_permit.so

session optional                        pam_umask.so

session required                        pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0022 skel=/etc/skel
session required        pam_unix.so
session optional                        pam_ldap.so
session optional        pam_systemd.so
```

/etc/pam.d/common-auth

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so use_first_pass

auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so

auth    required                        pam_permit.so

auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
```

/etc/pam.d/common-account

```
account [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so
account [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so

account requisite                       pam_deny.so

account required
```

/etc/pam.d/common-password

```
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
password        [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die]     pam_ldap.so use_authtok     try_first_pass

password        requisite                       pam_deny.so

password        required
```

Any ideas as to what could possibly be the culprit of this issue? If this info is incomplete then feel free to ask for any additional context that might be relevant. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I see the following in /var/log/auth.log on the client machine.

```
Feb 20 11:19:31 REDACTED nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap:///REDACTED: Invalid credentials
Feb 20 11:19:31 REDACTED nscd: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
Feb 20 11:19:31 REDACTED nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap:///REDACTED: Invalid credentials
Feb 20 11:19:31 REDACTED nscd: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server (sleeping 1 seconds)...
Feb 20 11:19:32 REDACTED nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap:///REDACTED: Invalid credentials
Feb 20 11:19:32 REDACTED nscd: nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable
Feb 20 11:19:42 REDACTED nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap:///REDACTED: Invalid credentials
Feb 20 11:19:42 REDACTED nscd: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
Feb 20 11:19:42 REDACTED nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap:///REDACTED: Invalid credentials
Feb 20 11:19:42 REDACTED nscd: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server (sleeping 1 seconds)...
Feb 20 11:19:43 REDACTED nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap:///REDACTED: Invalid credentials
Feb 20 11:19:43 REDACTED nscd: nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable
```

And, to reiterate, I can connect to the LDAP host via the LDAP client with ldapsearch using the exact same password that is in /etc/ldap.secret

EDIT 2: I tried changing the host server on the off chance that it was some firewall issue (though I don't know why ldapsearch would work in that case). Same exact issue.

Comment: @AaronCopley: So, to confirm, I should copy `session optional pam_ldap.so` to the other pam files?

Comment: @AaronCopley: Check the edit. Do those files look good?

Comment: @AaronCopley: `sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart` works fine. However, `sudo update-rc.d nslcd enable` returns `update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/nslcd: file does not exist`

Comment: @AaronCopley: Yeah, `sudo update-rc.d nscd enable` worked. `getent passwd` still doesn't see the LDAP users.

Comment: @AaronCopley: I'm not sure what you mean. I can search the LDAP host via the LDAP client via ldapsearch (I think that's what you mean by "authenticate"). Also, `getent passwd` works on the LDAP client. It just doesn't output any of the LDAP users create via the phpldapadmin console. In addition to not seeing the LDAP users via `getent passwd`, I can't `su` into the LDAP users on the client or `ssh` into the LDAP users remotely.

Comment: @Aaron Copley - `nslcd` and `nscd` are completely different programs. The former is a daemon LDAP authenticator (mandatory for libnss-ldapd & libpam-ldapd), the latter is (purely optional) caching daemon that is commonly used with *nix LDAP auth. Both names are valid in this context, but for different purposes.

Comment: @Gaios - both *these instructions* links in your question point to the same URL. The latter should point to an OS configuration howto.

Comment: @sam_pan_mariusz: Sorry. I completely butchered the links. It's accurate now.